# Is it possible to disable gutenberg in post but not on pages in wordress?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I am developing a WordPress website for a small business. The owner of the business is not tech savvy but has managed to learn to use the old WordPress editor. But he is having trouble with Gutenberg and wants me to remove it from the site. But I have used Gutenberg features to make home page and other pages in the website.

Since the owner only creates new post and not new pages I want to disable Gutenberg on post only and leave it enabled on pages. Is  this possible? And if yes then how do I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this code , Paste this code in functions.php file of your child theme or active theme.

```
// disable for posts
add_filter( 'use_block_editor_for_post', '__return_false', 10 );
```